# Plumbing better than using a library? Answer which links to a library was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I don't understand why my answer was deleted:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139759/633961

**The question**:

> I want to send a datetime.datetime object in serialized form from Python using JSON and de-serialize in JavaScript using JSON. What is the best way to do this?

**My answer**:

> Use a library. Maybe this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asjson

Why do so many people prefer plumbing to using a library?

I want to why an answer like mine gets deleted.

Comment: Because if you took out the link, or if the link died, what is your answer? "Use a library. Maybe this one *%#$%$#%$#*". Doesn't provide much value in itself. That's my guess at least.

Comment: If we take away the link from 'Use a library. Maybe this one', is there any information left?  If not, then the answer can (and often will) be deleted.

Comment: What you have is a link-only answer; it's only real value is the link it contains. If you take away the link - because it moves, the site goes down (even temporarily), etc. - then the answer has absolutely no value left. The point of SO is to be a repository of questions and answers; that means actual answers, not pointers to places that might contain answers. If you're going to suggest using a library you should also explain how that library can be used to solve the problem outlined in the question.

Comment: The link contains the name of the library. If pypi goes down (which possible, but many people depend on it), you can get the package from github (or what ever gets used by the library). Please provide more arguments :-) I am listening.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731, where all of this is covered. Your title is missing a word - *"Answer which **only** links to a library"* is the problem.

Comment: @guettli If you wanted to learn how to fish, and the only answer you got was "Use a fishing rod. Perhaps this specific fishing rod. <Link that contains the name of the fishing rod>." would you honestly be satisfied with that answer? Has that actually taught you how to fish?

Comment: I voted this question up because the user asks (without presumption) why their answer was deleted. I don't think it's good to downvote someone who is actually doing what we want them to do (bring their issue to meta).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I agree. But the problem is that there's a meta mentality of "Downvotes mean something different on meta. They mean people disagree." From what I remember reading when first coming to meta, that is only for [posts tagged feature-request](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) *"On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself"*

Comment: @codeMagic It means "I disagree" when there's something to disagree with. "Help me understand why my answer was deleted" doesn't seem like something to disagree on. "NO, WE WILL NOT HELP YOU UNDERSTAND WHY YOUR ANSWER WAS DELETED, GO AWAY." is what that says to a new user. Probably not the message we should be sending to new users. (Sorry for Caps, was integral to making my point).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I am completely agreeing with you. But I am saying the reason for the downvotes on questions like these are that people don't understand that part of the voting. I think many look at it and think "You believe it shouldn't be deleted but I think it should be so have a downvote". But I guess that's a discussion for another post

Answer (score 9):

Part of the problem is that without the link you would not even begin to answer the question. So if the link dies, your "answer" goes with it.

Secondly, you just point somewhere else. "Go there, use that". You fail to mention the why and the how. Why should he use it? How should he use it?

Show how, when using that specific library, the OP can solve his problems. Show a code sample that does what the OP wants to achieve and at the same time demonstrates why the library may be even more helpful than a custom solution.

If you do that, you'll end up with a far better answer.

Comment: The important part of my answer was "use a library". The link is not important. There are several libraries which implement the needed data processing.